# Should I have a new MongoDB connection per thread

Tags: node.js, multithreading, mongodb

When using the Node.js cluster library, should a connection to MongoDB be made in the master thread or in each child thread?

Firstly, can multiple threads use the same connection?

Secondly, would it be more performance-effective to use the same or separate connections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience, each child needs a connection, I use the following pattern in the app code for example

```
const cluster       = require('cluster');
const mongoose      = require('mongoose');
...

if (cluster.isMaster) { // Parent, only creates clusters
  global.processId = 'Master';
  for (let i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
      cluster.fork();
  }
  ...
} else { // Child cluster
    // connect
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myDB');
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The question suggests that the `cluster` library uses threads, but it does not, it uses processes.

Each process MUST have its own connection. Connections cannot be shared across a process.

Answer (score 0):

Every process should have its own connection.

Don't mix sessions. Use [connect-mongo](https://github.com/jdesboeufs/connect-mongo) for sessions.

Once client establishes session on one of the workers, it should not use any other instance for operations related to this client, this way you can cache clients on their respective server instances.

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate a little more? you mentioned sessions, are you referring to connections?

Comment: Basically you can use connect-mongo library to create MongoDB connection per each worker. Please check the library on how to do it.

Comment: Not interested in a library for such a simple task